# Finding linearly independent combination of vectors with a certain symmetry property

Tags: equation-solving

I have two linearly independent vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. Is there a way for me using Mathematica to find two linear combinations $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that:

1. $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent.
2. If I cut $w_2$ in half and re-order the halves to get $w_2'$, i.e. $w_2=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\rightarrow w_2'=\{4,5,6,1,2,3\}$, then $w_2'=w_1$?

$v_1$ and $v_2$ are chosen such that I am guaranteed $w_1$, $w_2$ exist.

Answer (score 2):

Funny problem. I like it. But there is must be something else in the condition of the problem? Or I misunderstand you.
You say that

> I am guaranteed that w1, w2 exist

Ok. Let's set

```
v1 = {0, 0, 0, 1};
v2 = {1, 0, 0, 0};
```

it's independent vectors.

Then find `w1` and `w2` in general case for this example:

```
w1 = v1*a1 + v2*b1
w2 = v1*a2 + v2*b2
(*{b1,0,0,a1}
{b2,0,0,a2}*)
```

Then find `w2trans` ($w_2'$)

```
w2trans = RotateLeft[w2, 2]
(*{0,a2,b2,0}*)
```

And `w2trans!=w1` in any cases. Is `w2trans` may be `{a1,0,b2,0}` in this example?

Comment: Thank-you very much for your answer, I will clarify my question. What I meant was that $v_1$, $v_2$ are chosen such that $w_1$, $w_2$ exist, they are not arbitrary. This problem arises in the context of the [Bogoliubov Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation), where I require a change of basis matrix $T$ to have the property that the upper left block equals the (complex conjugate of the) bottom right, and the upper right block equals the bottom left. The rows of $T$ are eigenvectors of some matrix, and I can take linear combinations of degenerate eigenvectors.

Comment: A proof that this is possible is provided at the very end of section II in [these notes](http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/archive/notes/fermions_and_jordan_wigner.pdf). However it does not give any algorithm for being able to do this.

Comment: ok, give me `v1` and `v2` for check my algorithm

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance. One set of examples is: v1 = {0.65566, 0.262264, 0, 0.0364256, -0.65566, -0.262264, 0, -0.0364256}; v2 = {0, -0.0802896, 0, -0.702534, 0, -0.0802896, 0, -0.702534}. In this case I can construct w1, w2 manually via: {w1,w2}={v1 + v2, v2 - v1}.

Another case is: v1 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.707107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.707107}; v2 = {0, 0, 0, 0.707107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.707107, 0, 0, 0, 0}.

Comment: Another case: v1={0.707107, 0, 0, 0, -0.707107, 0, 0, 0}; v2={0, 0, 0, -0.707107, 0, 0, 0, -0.707107}, and as before {w1,w2}={v1 + V2, v2 - v1}.